# Regex extract substring after '=' sign

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I saw many examples, but for some reason it still does not work for me.

This is the command I'm executing:

```
NUMBER=$(docker logs vault | grep Token)
NUMBER=${NUMBER##*": "}
NUMBER=$(echo $NUMBER | sed 's/^token=(.*)$//g')
echo $NUMBER
```

I want to get the value after '=', which is a string basically.
I tried using GREP, and other regex's but I either get nothing, or just the original string.

Please advise.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: You're a) using `()` capture groups with Basic Regular Expressions, where they have to be `\(\)` (or use ERE instead, `sed -E`/`sed -r`) and b) you're removing the complete line, but you want to re-insert the captured group again.

Comment: Better to use `cut` here `echo 'token=dsa32e3' | cut -d= -f2`

Comment: Or, if supported, `number=$(echo token=dsa32e3);number=${number#*=}`

Comment: in bash: `NUMBER=${tk/*=/} ; echo $NUMBER`, assuming tk="token=dsa32e3"

Comment: @anubhava, thank you! please post an answer so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text after a delimiter better to use `cut` instead of `sed` as in this example:

```
echo 'token=dsa32e3' | cut -d= -f2
```

```
dsa32e3
```

- `-d=` sets delimiter as `=` for `cut`
- `-f1` makes `cut` print first field

Comment: I encounter another at the moment, I get back the string I wanted but with an additional ANSI character:
"48372d06-03a5-f2a0-8428-ecd58cf57424\u001b[0m", what is this '\u001b[0m' string? and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Is this `\u001b[0m` part of your original string as well?

Comment: Nope, it's seems to be added after I use the grep command.

Comment: But there is no `grep` here.. Just a `cut` command. If your script has more than it then I suggest you provide a sample input and your script by editing your question so that I can investigate and suggest you a fix.

Comment: I've added the additional command I perform.

Comment: ok can you tell me output of this command: `docker logs vault | awk -F= '/Token/{print $2}' | cat -A`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165576/discussion-between-david-faiz-and-anubhava).

Comment: Solved it using sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
The string at the end was ANSI colour code.

Comment: Oh ok glad you made it work. cheers

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you can simply remove the `token=`, with

```
NUMBER=$(echo token=dsa32e3 | sed 's/^token=//g') 
echo $NUMBER
```

Other non-regexp based alternatives are possible, as other users pointed out.

Another fun possibility is using the negative lookbehind, not supported by `sed`, so I used `perl`.

```
NUMBER=$(echo token=dsa32e3 | perl -pe 's/.*(?<=token=)([a-z0-9]*)/$1/g')
echo $NUMBER
```